# List tags always shows 0

Tags: css, list, html-lists

I have used an unordered list with some CSS styles. Now, all the list items are showing 0. 
I have given the list-style property as none because I want to display some specific number styles. Am I missing something?

```css
ol.circle li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(item);
  background: #0971B2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

ol.circle {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<ol class="circle">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to increment the counter on each `li` element with `counter-increment` property and the value is the counter you want to increment.

```css
ul.circle li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(item);
  background: #0971B2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.circle {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ul class="circle">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```